# mod_security whitelist file

Tags: ip, apache, whitelist, mod-security

How can I add IP to my mod_security "whitelist.file" when all IPS begins like that 90.12.131. will be open?

I try to add ^ before IP but it dosn't work.
^90.12.131

Please, Someone? 
Thanks,
Oz.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^90\.12\.131" "phase:1,nolog,allow"
```

or

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 90.12.131.0/24" "phase:1,nolog,allow"
```

write in a file,like this

whitelist.file,a dot end with it

> 90.12.131.

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@pmf whitelist.file" "phase:1,nolog,allow"
```